# Bottom navigation with fragments and a bar on top of the selected item as following image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

As this image shows a bar on the selected item . How can i get it?
[image]

Comment: **Make a custom view and add it up in a horizontal linear layout !**

Comment: "vary from device to device" what do you mean? Based on this answer, using a LinearLayout totally works.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to make **Custom Layout**  :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/selector"
                android:background="@color/selector_color"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />  <!--Mind the case here-->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Use the `ClickEvents` to toggle visibility of the `selector`

**It will not vary from device to device**. I suggest if you use `ConstraintLayout` with `match_constraint` attribute and `guidelines`.

[Docs for Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline)

Comment: @deadfish fixed. thanx for mentioning :)